# Why can the local administartor access a site collection?

Tags: administration, site-collection, site, user-accounts, access

I'm stumped by an access phenomenon because I am not sure how the permisssons for accessing a site collection work in this specific scenario:

Even though I shouln't be able to do so, I am accessing my site collection via Webbrowser logged on as my built-in local windows administrator (BUILTIN/Administrator) (who is also a farm administrator).

- BUILTIN/Administrator is not a site collection admin
- BUILTIN/Administrator is not a member in any site collection group

And according to [this technet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288077) by Microsoft I shouldn't be allowed to access my site collection! Can someone explain how come I can still access my site collection anyway?

All other user accounts that are members of the windows administrators group get the access denied error. Only BUILTIN/Administrator does not.

I'm currently doing security consulting work and need clearity on this issue.

**Note:**
I am using a SharePoint 2010 Foundation standalone installation on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your web application user policy and see if builtin\administrators have full control.

Comment: That did the trick! My BUILTIN/Administrator did have full control for the web application and no other user did. Thanks for the hint! :-)

Comment: Before you remove that user check that you're not using it as Search content access account